# How to access external Storage in Tizen Smart TVs

Tags: api, filesystems, mount, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I need yout help to find out how to write and read files from external usb storage from Tizen Smart TVs. Problem starts when detecting it

```
`
/**
 * Hello World Sample Project
 */
// import Label component
var Label = caph.require('ui.base.component.Label');

caph.app.addScene('main', $class({
    $extends : caph.require('ui.base.Scene'),

    // oncreate is called when the scene is created
    oncreate : function() {
        // add "Hello World"

        this.addChild(new Label({
            text : 'Hello World',
            size : [ 500, 100 ],
            position : [ 300, 400 ]
        }).setTextSize('72px').setStyle({
            backgroundColor : 'red',
            color : 'white'
        }));

        /// Here the filesystem showd show me all the storages
        tizen.filesystem.listStorages(checkCorruptedRemovableDrives);
    }
})).run();
`
```

And here is the Success callback, this show me how much storages I have.
    `
    /* Success event handler */
    var checkCorruptedRemovableDrives = function(storages) {

```
    /// Here I will kow how much storages I have
    console.log(storages.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < storages.length; i++) {
        if (storages[i].type != "EXTERNAL")
            continue;
        if (storages[i].state == "UNMOUNTABLE")
            console.log("External drive " + storages[i].label + " is corrupted.");
    }
};
`
```

Here is the method thrown when there are errors, this is never called.
    
    `var checkCorruptedRemovableDrivesError = function(storages){
        console.log("Error");
    }`

Now, the console output is aways a simple `0` meanning I have no storage (but I have the internal one and two usb ones mounted).

Has Anyone faced this problem or have any Idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Tizen TV always uses "removable2" as label for USB.
So you don't need to use listStorage and getStorage.

Multiple USBs are distinguished as "removable2/sda1", "removable2/sda2"

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve("removable2", function(e){
        e.listFiles(function(r){
            for(i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
                tizen.filesystem.resolve(r[i].path + r[i].name, function(t){
                    //You resolve USB root. Do something you want with USB.
                }, function(t){
                    console.log("resolve error for " + r[i].path + r[i].name);
                    console.log(t);                
                }, "rw"); //you should use rw permission, to write something in usb.
            }
        });               
    },function(e){
        console.log("removable2 resolve error");
        console.log(e);
    }, "r"); // permission should be given as r for removable2
```

Here is test app made by me. and you can check how to use SDK 1.5

http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/3ad8bd6023af18a7?forumID=d88a711f47dc6e9f

This app is working in both of TV and SDK 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Web Simulator?
APIs don't work in Web Simulator properly. It can't simulate things well.

When I check listStorage in 'emulator', it throws list of storages.
but even though I can get list of storage, I can't use it in filesystem. It is bug of SDK 1.4.

SDK 1.5 will have test features for USB storage, and it is planned to release in a month. Wait for a month :(

Comment: Thanks, but I am using a real TV to perform the tests.

Comment: Hello. SDK 1.5 is released. and I get filesystem working properly both on SDK and TV. SDK can't get state change listener event, and bug in displayed state, but it can get file list properly. TV device is working very well.